# GW routing between three hosts in VM environment

Tags: linux, networking, routing, virtualization

I want to create a setup in Linux where the traffic between two hosts (HostA and HostC) will pass over a third host (HostB) which will act as a GW for VM1.
I have three VMs:

1. HostA with ens0: 10.10.0.2/24
2. HostB with ens0: 10.10.0.3/24 and ens1: 192.168.0.1/24
3. HostC with ens1: 192.168.0.2/24

HostA routing table:

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens0
192.168.0.1     10.10.0.3       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens0
192.168.0.2     10.10.0.3       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens0
```

HostB routing table, acting as GW for HostA:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens1
```

HostC routing table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.2      192.168.0.1   255.255.255.255     UGH   0      0        0 ens1
192.168.0.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0     U     0      0        0 ens1
```

Unfortunately when I try to check the new routing table, I don't see the traffic from HostA to hit HostC. I see the traffic from A on both interfaces of B, but not on C. On C I only see occasional ARP requests from the GW (HostB)

I have configured on all machines IP forwarding using the command:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo service procps restart
```

Comment: Well, the GW of Host A and C naturally has to be the IP of Host B, more precisely the one matching their own subnetwork. Also, ip_forward is only necessary for hosts that forward packets, so only Host B.

Comment: You don't need `service procps restart`. It'd undo `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` if `/etc/sysctl.conf` contains `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0`.

Comment: I have done everything you asked but when I stream unicast streaming from HostA -> HostC I don't see the traffic hitting HostC, I can see it present on both interfaces on HostB. I have changed the `/etc/sysctl.conf` and enabled IPv4 packet forwarding and then restarted the server but it didn't help.